# Dependency between main application and service

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have an mobile application that logins via WCF service. When client click login button, I sent username and password to service and get result.

Service returns result as LoginResponse class. In the mobile side I don't want to use this LoginResponse to not being dependent with service.

So I need a best practice design about working with services.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information. Do you control the service or do you just use it? What kind of binding do you use? To what frmat are the responses serialized? ...

Comment: LoginResponse should just be a DataContract and there is no need to have a service dependency. I put DataContracts in a separate dll and share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to another answer I offered about 2 hours ago... you have the contractual definitions for the service (i.e. the interface and any entities) in a separate assembly. The service references that and is the implementation of that contract. The client also references that contractual assembly.

The client uses the [`System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class to create a factory that will give you a connection to the WCF service. The MSDN article [*How to: Use the ChannelFactory*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx) gives a simple example of this.

This method removes any references to the physical service - there is no generated proxy, no service reference. The only thing you have to keep track of is the endpoint address and what type of binding to use (this can be done via config files as you'll see from many of the examples floating around).